# PHP MySQL concurrentcy with limited maximum items in database

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am working on an application that limits absolute maximum number of users singed up for event, using php and mysql.

On each sing up, I query the database first, to check how many users are already signed.

If there is still place left, then new row gets inserted and if it isn't, error is returned to user.

What is the best way to prevent that operation of signing up to be interrupted by parallel request? Say:

- user 1 queries database, there is one place left
- user 2 jumps in, queries, also sees one place left
- user 1 signs up
- user 2 signs up

So I would end up with one user more than absolute maximum. I have been reading up on transactions and locks, but am not sure what to use in this situation.

Is it enough to start a transaction before select and commit right after insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into Transaction isolation levels:

> Isolation is typically defined at database level as a property that defines how/when the changes made by one operation become visible to other.

There are 4 isolation levels. They may depend on the database you are using but they are likely to these:

**Serializable**

This is the highest isolation level.

With a lock-based concurrency control DBMS implementation, serializability requires read and write locks (acquired on selected data) to be released at the end of the transaction. Also range-locks must be acquired when a SELECT query uses a ranged WHERE clause, especially to avoid the phantom reads phenomenon (see below).

When using non-lock based concurrency control, no locks are acquired; however, if the system detects a write collision among several concurrent transactions, only one of them is allowed to commit. See snapshot isolation for more details on this topic.

**Repeatable reads**

In this isolation level, a lock-based concurrency control DBMS implementation keeps read and write locks (acquired on selected data) until the end of the transaction. However, range-locks are not managed, so phantom reads can occur.

**Read committed**

In this isolation level, a lock-based concurrency control DBMS implementation keeps write locks (acquired on selected data) until the end of the transaction, but read locks are released as soon as the SELECT operation is performed (so the non-repeatable reads phenomenon can occur in this isolation level, as discussed below). As in the previous level, range-locks are not managed.

Putting it in simpler words, read committed is an isolation level that guarantees that any data read is committed at the moment it is read. It simply restricts the reader from seeing any intermediate, uncommitted, 'dirty' read. It makes no promise whatsoever that if the transaction re-issues the read, it will find the same data; data is free to change after it is read.

**Read uncommitted**

This is the lowest isolation level. In this level, dirty reads are allowed, so one transaction may see not-yet-committed changes made by other transactions.

Since each isolation level is stronger than those below, in that no higher isolation level allows an action forbidden by a lower one, the standard permits a DBMS to run a transaction at an isolation level stronger than that requested (e.g., a "Read committed" transaction may actually be performed at a "Repeatable read" isolation level).

You want to look into Serializable. Source: Wikipedia (read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)).